# Java after some time (time to live) variable should be deleted from the memory

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

In simple client server program java,we are getting key value and ttl from client, **If there is a time to live (ttl) value set for the key, it should be deleted from the memory once ttl is expired.
input is key value time_to_live**
Eg:
hi there 60
In the above case the key hi should be deleted, 60 seconds after it has been set. Any Idea on this one ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i dont even know how to set the time limit in java thats the problem :(

Comment: This isn't a tutorial site. Do some research, make an attempt, and come back when you have a specific question or problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects here.

First of all, Java is a garbage collected language. This means that you don't have *full* control over the point in time when an object gets *collected*. The aspect under your control is: "alive" references pointing to that object. As soon as no alive reference points to some object, that object becomes eligible for garbage collection. And then the GC will decide when to get rid of that object.

But your question is (most likely) going into a different direction. What you need to do: implement your own *cache* classes. Those could simply take a timestamp when a new entry is added; and then there is a monitor thread that runs every x seconds. The monitor thread simply removes all entries in the cache that have a timestamp "before" your lifetime.

Of course: this is not an easy thing to implement (as you have to avoid race conditions between that monitor thread and other threads trying to read from the cache).